# How to get the reference of the built graph using Dagger2 DI?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have an PerActivity component. I build the graph in the onCreate of the activity like this:

```
 mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(BrowserApp.getAppComponent())
            .activityModule(new ActivityModule())
            .build();
```

It is pretty straight forward to get reference of `mActivityComponent` in fragments. I can use this for it:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getActivityComponent();
```

The problem arises in other classes. Let's say I have a webView which doesn't have a method like `getActivity()`. How should I get a reference to `mActivityComponent`? If I pass the reference in the constructor, doesn't it defeat the purpose of using Dependency Injection? 
And I cannot make it static, because then it won't be "PerActivity" anymore, it will be one and same for all activities.

Comment: What do you need to share between the activity and a view? Ideally views should just be responsible for displaying data and the controller interfaces with the view. There's probably a better way for these to communicate than DI.

Comment: I just gave an example, not just view, it can be any class. I have used Dagger2 before with an application level component, which was static, so there was no issue in getting a reference to it.
Let's say I want to send a signal on the Bus when I receive title of a webpage in the WebChromeClient class. How do I inject the WebChromeClient class?